# PyOpenGL or OpenGL picking question (Not color picking)

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt5, pyopengl

I have a small python program that uses `PyOpenGL` libraries to draw to spheres. The code has the below process

- draw spheres

  if there is a hit, then uses the below

  ```
  SELECT_BUFFER_SIZE = 512
  x, y = event.x(), event.y()
  # required to call this to force PyQt to read from the correct, updated buffer
  viewport = glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT)
  # print viewport
  w = viewport[2] - viewport[0]
  h = viewport[3] - viewport[1]
  aspect_ratio = w / h


  glSelectBuffer(SELECT_BUFFER_SIZE)
  glRenderMode(GL_SELECT)

  glInitNames()
  glPushName(0)

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
  glPushMatrix()
  glLoadIdentity()
  gluPickMatrix(x, viewport[3] - y, 5, 5, viewport)

  glOrtho( *** setting the schene***) 

  **-draw spheres using glLoadName(for each)**

  glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
  glPopMatrix()
  glFlush()

  buffer = glRenderMode(GL_RENDER)

  # print buffer
  for hit_record in buffer:
      _, _, names = hit_record
      print(names)
  ```

But when I try to print the names, although I hit only one of them on the window, both names are printed. What should be the solution for that

In short, I am trying to draw three spheres(in white color) in a Pyqt5 window using PyOpenGL with the same colors, but I am trying to make them eligible for picking. I have also the capabilities of rotating, moving, and zoom in-out. So these capabilities should not break picking when they are done.(As it is asked in the comment, it is not homework. It is a side project that I work on for the last 2 years. So this problem is only a really small portion of my code.)

Comment: Is this an exercise / homework assignment? If so, maybe tell your teacher / TA / professor, that selection mode never was particularly well supported, has been *removed* entirely from modern OpenGL, and using it will fall back to a software fallback implementation, because no GPU works *that* way. If you want to do OpenGL picking the right way, either render into an index buffer (not to be confused with index color mode) or use scissored occlusion queries.

Comment: It is not an assignment. I am working on this as a side project for my needs. Spheres are just examples here, but what I am trying to work on this much bigger than this. Do you mind pointing some examples for the right way? I can turn my focus into that easily.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure at all that this will help
 and I confess that I didn't read the actual code, 
 and I didn't quite understood if the spheres were colliding between them or with the border itself

I once had a tiny bit similar problem that I couldn't understand for too much time.
 but basically a hit was printed twice because both of the objects were registering a hit, 
 so whenever they've hit each other two hit messages were printed.

I used their ID(or place in a list or something similar)
so only one of them (the one with the bigger ID) will print the message

I have no idea if that helps but it might just be it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But the problem here is when I turn the scene I only get the first sphere as the hit although I have selected the second. I am still empty of how to solve this problem.